# Can you turn off your Xbox while it's loading?

Tags: xbox-360

I wouldn't turn off my Xbox but I do not know if I should because I don't want to make it messed up and not working anymore. It's loading very long. What can it mean when it loads very long?

Comment: When is it taking long? When you first turn it on or for games ?

Comment: More details would be good, but if it really is just loading, yeah go ahead and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Yes.

It's not advised by most companies to switch off a device when it is starting up but it should not have too much of an effect. Where is it loading? If it's while you're signing in (with an Xbox live account) or after sign in and before the main screen  then it's most likely a problem with your internet.

Answer (score 0):

Turning your Xbox off while loading it not a problem. Although you should never turn it off while saving, else you risk save file corruption.